# Will restarting the computer a lot (about 8 times in succession) damage the laptop?

Tags: windows-10

I am just restarting the laptop normally from the sign-in screen buttons. Would that damage the laptop or just add wear and tear on the parts inside?

Comment: There's an infinitesimal amount of wear and tear when you restart, but nowhere near enough to worry about.

Answer (score 1):

**Restarting is just like using your computer normally.**

Assuming your computer is in good working condition (e.g. fans are working and the computer isn't at risk of overheating) there's nothing unique to the process of starting/restarting your computer versus just using it. In either case the processor performs calculations, primary storage devices store and retrieve data, main memory is accessed, etc. Restarting your computer thousands of times is no different in terms of *wear* than leaving it on and running programs.